# How to get 32bit wx-widget dev libraries on linux 64bit

Tags: c++, linux, build, include, wxwidgets

I am trying to build a 32 bit C++ project and compiler tells me it cant find the wx/wx.h and some other wx header files.I got wx libraries for 64bit but i still got the wx/wx.h : No such file or directory error.
   Is there anyway I can install 32 bit i386 libraries on my 64bit linux as default wx libraries ?

Comment: Most linux distros have some sort of multilib support, which should let you install the 32bit libs.

Comment: How can I do that ? I am a newbie on linux.

Comment: Well what distro are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 ..

Comment: Look for a version of the package labeled i386 in the repos then, and install that one.

Comment: Already tried it ,I cant find it in the packages,so I just compiled the library from source code.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling it then. It seems that the linker cant find the required files.

Comment: classical ./configure ,make,make install way,the files are all there.Just the linker cant find them.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your project. Bit ambiguous there...

Comment: There is a special build.py file that auto generates makefiles then compiles the source code.

Comment: Try putting  the library files somewhere that the linker will find them (try /bin, or the same directory as your project.) Otherwise, you can try modifying the generated makefiles with absolute paths to the required files

Comment: I dont think they will work ib bin cause they are header files.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Have you tried the other methods?

Comment: since you are installing from packages or source and not a package manager, you have to install all dependencies which i suspect is your issue.